# Python function to increase number when root multipliers are above a ratio of 1:2

Tags: python, nameerror

I am trying to take a number that is a multiple of 6 and after calculating the closest square root multiplier I then want to make sure that the multipliers are no higher than a ratio of 1:2 to each other and if so raise the number by 6.

The idea being that a user gives a number that is a multiple of 6

and if that numbers root multiplies are above a ration of 1:2
then the number is increased to an accepted number whose root multipliers are below a ration of 1:2

meaning that if the user entered 360, this would be accepted as
18 * 20 is below a ration of 1:2 or 18:36 and the code would return

```
360
18
20
```

but 366 would be rejected as its multipliers 6 * 61 are above the ration of 1:2 and in this instance i would like to return the number 378 along with the root multipliers of 18 * 21 which fall below a ration of 1:2

I finally got it working, thanks for all the help in the comments and chitown88 for taking the time to write an answer.

Code:

```
from math import sqrt
import os

i = 366

def my_function(i):
  global x
  global y

  sq_rt = sqrt(i)
  a = str(sq_rt)
  vAP = a.split('.')[1]
  vAP = int(vAP)

  if vAP == 0:
    my_int = int(sq_rt)
    otr_num = i / my_int
    otr_int = int(otr_num)
    x = str(my_int)
    y = str(otr_int)

  else:
    rnd = int(sq_rt)
    res = i/rnd
    b = str(res)
    vAPb = b.split('.')[1]
    vAPb = int(vAPb)

    if vAPb == 0:
      x = str(rnd)
      y = str(int(float(b)))

    else:  
      while (i % rnd != 0):
        rnd = rnd - 1
      else:
        e = i/rnd
        x = str(rnd)
        y = str(int(e))
      
  return x
  return y
my_function(i)

while not (x * 2 >= y):
  my_function(i)  
  i += 6

print(i)
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: well, on this line `while (x * 2 >= y):` neither x nor y are defined. What do you expect? Please, check [ask] and always post full traceback you get.

Comment: Also, don't spam tags. 4 out of 5 tags are irrelevant to the problem

Comment: Thats what i am confused about, is how can i define them given that in order for my while statement to run they need the values that can only be retrieved from the if else statement that runs inside the loop. and sorry about the tags

Comment: You'll need to set an initial value for them.

Comment: but the initial value has to be relevant to the outcome of the if else statement that lives inside the while loop as the number i is an input from a user so it could be anything meaning that x and y could also be anything

Comment: IT can be anything...sure. But it needs to start somewhere. I could work this out for you (by the way there are some other errors in the code that need to be addressed), but I'm not quite sure of what the expected output here is. Is `i` an number the user will input?

Comment: i is a number the user will input

Comment: iv added a function with the global variables and but the while loop is now running indefinitely

Answer (score 1):

1. The error is telling exactly the problem. You are trying to check if x * 2 >= y, but there are no values assigned to those variables initially. You need to set an initial value for x and y. Are you sure you want to run while that condition is True? Check my solution below.
2. You also have another error here. You set x and y as strings. So when it goes back to the logic, when x is 6 for example, x * 2 will yield '66', not 12. So I fixed that too.
3. You need to overwrite your i variable. `i + 6` won't change the value of `i` unless you re-assign it. You can do it either by `i = i + 6` or simply `i += 6`.
4. Lastly, this loop will run forever. Consider adding some way to stop the while loop after a certain number of iterations, or when interrupted by a keyboard stroke.

**Code:**

```
from math import sqrt
import os

max_iterations = 100
it = 1

i = 360

while it <= max_iterations:

  sq_rt = sqrt(i)
  a = str(sq_rt)
  vAP = a.split('.')[1]
  vAP = int(vAP)

  if vAP == 0:
    my_int = int(sq_rt)
    otr_num = i / my_int
    otr_int = int(otr_num)
    x = str(my_int)
    y = str(otr_int)

  else:
    rnd = int(sq_rt)
    res = i/rnd
    b = str(res)
    vAPb = b.split('.')[1]
    vAPb = int(vAPb)

    if vAPb == 0:
      x = rnd
      y = int(float(b))

    else:  
      while (i % rnd != 0):
        rnd = rnd - 1
      else:
        e = i/rnd
        x = rnd
        y = int(e)
      
  ans = x*y
  print(f'{x} * {y} = {ans}')

  i += 6
  it += 1
```

**Output:**

```
18 * 20 = 360
6 * 61 = 366
12 * 31 = 372
18 * 21 = 378
16 * 24 = 384
15 * 26 = 390
18 * 22 = 396
6 * 67 = 402
17 * 24 = 408
18 * 23 = 414
20 * 21 = 420
6 * 71 = 426
18 * 24 = 432
6 * 73 = 438
12 * 37 = 444
18 * 25 = 450
19 * 24 = 456
21 * 22 = 462
18 * 26 = 468
6 * 79 = 474
20 * 24 = 480
18 * 27 = 486
12 * 41 = 492
6 * 83 = 498
21 * 24 = 504
17 * 30 = 510
12 * 43 = 516
18 * 29 = 522
22 * 24 = 528
6 * 89 = 534
20 * 27 = 540
21 * 26 = 546
23 * 24 = 552
18 * 31 = 558
12 * 47 = 564
19 * 30 = 570
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I managed to get it working by tweaking my wrapping my if else into a function that produced and returning x and y as global variables and then further calling this function into my loop using i += 6 as the break argument